# Expo EAS build use of undeclared identifier 'Promise'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

I am migrating my managed Expo React Native project to the EAS build ecosystem and am getting a strange error that I dont see anywhere else when googling around.

The following error happens while running the `Fastlane` part of the build:

```
❌  (node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/JSI/ExpoModulesProxySpec.mm:12:118)

10 | using PromiseInvocationBlock = void (^)(RCTPromiseResolveBlock resolveWrapper, RCTPromiseRejectBlock rejectWrapper);
11 | 
> 12 | static void callPromiseSetupWithBlock(jsi::Runtime &runtime, std::shared_ptr<CallInvoker> jsInvoker, std::shared_ptr<Promise> promise, PromiseInvocationBlock setupBlock)
    |                                                                                                                      ^ use of undeclared identifier 'Promise'
13 | {
14 |   auto weakResolveWrapper = CallbackWrapper::createWeak(promise->resolve_.getFunction(runtime), runtime, jsInvoker);
15 |   auto weakRejectWrapper = CallbackWrapper::createWeak(promise->reject_.getFunction(runtime), runtime, jsInvoker);
2543

❌  (node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/JSI/ExpoModulesProxySpec.mm:14:29)

12 | static void callPromiseSetupWithBlock(jsi::Runtime &runtime, std::shared_ptr<CallInvoker> jsInvoker, std::shared_ptr<Promise> promise, PromiseInvocationBlock setupBlock)
13 | {
> 14 |   auto weakResolveWrapper = CallbackWrapper::createWeak(promise->resolve_.getFunction(runtime), runtime, jsInvoker);
    |                             ^ incomplete type 'facebook::react::CallbackWrapper' named in nested name specifier
15 |   auto weakRejectWrapper = CallbackWrapper::createWeak(promise->reject_.getFunction(runtime), runtime, jsInvoker);
16 | 
17 |   __block BOOL resolveWasCalled = NO;
2544

❌  (node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/JSI/ExpoModulesProxySpec.mm:15:28)

13 | {
14 |   auto weakResolveWrapper = CallbackWrapper::createWeak(promise->resolve_.getFunction(runtime), runtime, jsInvoker);
> 15 |   auto weakRejectWrapper = CallbackWrapper::createWeak(promise->reject_.getFunction(runtime), runtime, jsInvoker);
    |                            ^ incomplete type 'facebook::react::CallbackWrapper' named in nested name specifier
16 | 
17 |   __block BOOL resolveWasCalled = NO;
18 |   __block BOOL rejectWasCalled = NO;
2545

❌  (node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/JSI/ExpoModulesProxySpec.mm:95:91)

93 | 
94 |   // The function that is invoked as a setup of the JS `Promise`.
> 95 |   auto promiseSetupFunc = [expoModulesProxy, args](jsi::Runtime &runtime, std::shared_ptr<Promise> promise) {
    |                                                                                           ^ use of undeclared identifier 'Promise'
96 |     callPromiseSetupWithBlock(runtime, expoModulesProxy->jsInvoker_, promise, ^(RCTPromiseResolveBlock resolver, RCTPromiseRejectBlock rejecter) {
97 |       NSString *moduleName = convertJSIStringToNSString(runtime, args[0].getString(runtime));
98 |       NSString *methodName = convertJSIStringToNSString(runtime, args[1].getString(runtime));
2546

❌  error:
```

As you can see it is telling me Promise is undefined. The call stack looks like its trying to load promises while it breaks, but I'm not too sure.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
"scripts": {
  "start": "expo start --dev-client",
  "android": "expo run:android",
  "ios": "expo run:ios",
  "web": "expo start --web",
  "eject": "expo eject",
  "test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
  "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0.1",
  "@expo/match-media": "0.3.0",
  "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.0",
  "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
  "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.3.2",
  "@react-native-community/viewpager": "5.0.11",
  "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.4.0",
  "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.4",
  "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.1.0",
  "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.2",
  "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
  "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
  "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.10.0",
  "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.35.0",
  "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.18.1",
  "eas-cli": "^2.1.0",
  "expo": "~46.0.9",
  "expo-auth-session": "~3.7.1",
  "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
  "expo-calendar": "~10.3.0",
  "expo-checkbox": "~2.2.0",
  "expo-dev-client": "~1.2.1",
  "expo-device": "~4.3.0",
  "expo-facebook": "~12.2.0",
  "expo-google-sign-in": "~11.0.0",
  "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.4.0",
  "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
  "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
  "expo-modules-autolinking": "^0.10.3",
  "expo-notifications": "~0.16.1",
  "expo-random": "~12.3.0",
  "expo-screen-orientation": "~4.3.0",
  "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
  "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
  "expo-updates": "~0.14.5",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "firebase": "^9.6.7",
  "firebase-functions": "^3.13.1",
  "google-map-react": "^2.1.10",
  "google-maps-react": "^2.0.6",
  "idb": "^7.0.1",
  "modal-enhanced-react-native-web": "^0.2.0",
  "modal-react-native-web": "^0.2.0",
  "ngeohash": "^0.6.3",
  "react": "18.0.0",
  "react-calendar": "^3.1.0",
  "react-collapsible": "^2.10.0",
  "react-dom": "18.1.0",
  "react-dropdown": "^1.10.0",
  "react-google-autocomplete": "^2.6.1",
  "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
  "react-native": "0.69.1",
  "react-native-anchor-point": "^1.0.1",
  "react-native-calendar-strip": "^2.0.9",
  "react-native-calendars": "^1.1285.0",
  "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
  "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.1",
  "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
  "react-native-elements": "^3.0.0-alpha.1",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.6.0",
  "react-native-gifted-chat": "^1.0.4",
  "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
  "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
  "react-native-maps": "1.3.1",
  "react-native-material-ripple": "^0.9.1",
  "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
  "react-native-paypal": "^4.1.0",
  "react-native-ratings": "^8.0.3",
  "react-native-read-more-text": "^1.1.2",
  "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.1",
  "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
  "react-native-responsive-ui": "^2.1.1",
  "react-native-screens": "~3.17.0",
  "react-native-svg": "13.1.0",
  "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
  "react-native-video": "^5.2.0",
  "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
  "react-native-web-hover": "^0.2.9",
  "react-native-web-maps": "^0.3.0",
  "react-native-webview": "11.23.1",
  "react-number-format": "^4.4.1",
  "react-paypal-button-v2": "^2.6.2",
  "react-pro-sidebar": "^0.7.1",
  "react-responsive": "^8.1.0",
  "react-ripples": "^2.2.1",
  "react-select": "^5.4.0",
  "react-time-picker": "^4.5.0",
  "save": "^2.4.0",
  "expo-build-properties": "~0.3.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.12.10",
  "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
  "babel-preset-expo": "~9.2.0",
  "jest": "^29.0.3",
  "typescript": "^4.6.3"
},
"private": true,
"name": "React",
"version": "1.0.0"
}
```

The cocoapods seem to install successfully.
Anyone know whats causing this error?

Comment: I dont know if it helps you,i was getting failed builds when i had forgotten git ignored some of my files

Comment: @Vaggelis I only have a handful on files listed in my .gitIgnore file so I dont think its the culprit in my case. I will try removing some items from the list however and see if the build works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by removing `@react-native-firebase/app` from the plugins section in my `apps.json` file and changing the `useFrameworks` flag to `static`:

```
"plugins": [
  "@react-native-firebase/app", //remove this
  [
    "expo-build-properties",
      {
        "ios": {
           "useFrameworks": "static"
         }
      }
   ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`yarn add expo-modules-core` from [this comment](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/15871#issuecomment-1154569705) helped